# how to get the header values of an attached excel sheet in MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC3 Razor project i have a a doubt.
Situation is this:
    1) I have a front end and i had a Fileupload and have button for next page navigation.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConvertToUniCode", "Import", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) { 

        <table>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Choose File:<input id="selectfile" type='file' data-val="true" data-val-required="please select a file" name='file' /></label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Next" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
       }
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult ConvertToUniCode(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
        //HttpPostedFile file= new HttpPostedFile();
            if(file.ContentLength>0)
            {
                string fileName =Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ImportFileHome/"+ fileName);
                file.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileSavePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);


//Here i need to get the header coloumn values.
            }
2) In the Second page i have a DropDownListFor control for binding the header values one by one.
3) Todo that i need to read the excel sheet header coloumn values.
```

The Excel sheet be like this.

```
-------------------------------
  Name   |   Age   | Address |    ==> Coloum Header
-------------------------------
jasper   | 26      |India    |
```

I need to get the Header values Name,Age,Address.
How to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OLEDB.  You can gather this from [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/f8bfc7a2-91ef-4558-8ac8-910b2fdfeee8/) which defines this code using a DataTable approach:

```
DataTable schemaTable = connection.GetSchema("Columns");
// Each row can then get the column via:
string name = (string)row["COLUMN_NAME"];
```